# Getting an error when clicking lightning:radioGroup - in Android Mobile, Spring 19 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Everytime I click a **lightning:radioGroup**, a popup appears - with the error message: "Sorry to interrupt". This is new to Spring 17. It used to work in the previous release.

[image]

The code looks like below:

```
<aura:attribute name="yesno" type="List" default="[ {'label': 'Yes', 'value': 'Yes'}, {'label': 'No', 'value': 'No'} ]"/> 
<lightning:radioGroup name="PreferredName" aura:id="PreferredName" label="Preferred Name" options="{! v.yesno }" type="button"/>
```

Simply add that to a lightning page, then view it in Chrome (with mobile activated in Dev Tools) Or view it from the SF mobile app in Android.

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Do you mean spring 19?

Comment: Yes I do mean Spring 19. Updating now. Thanks.